# Print position in console

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, source-engine

Is it possible?

I know I can see the actual position with cl_showpos 1

But copying it would help me and speed some things up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The command `getpos` or `getpos_exact` should give you a `setpos` command in console.